# Getting runtime error 1004 when having copy/paste function

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting this error when trying to compile this. What is the right way to copy the cell and paste to another sheet?

Sub copypaste()

```
Dim col As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim copy As String
Dim newrow As Integer
Dim wrksht As Integer

wrksht = 3
newrow = 1


For col = 23 To 1 Step -1
    Worksheets(3).Cells(33, col).copy
    Worksheets(17).Cells(row, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    For row = 31 To 1 Step -1
        If Worksheets(3).Cells(row, col).Value = "x" Then


            Worksheets(17).Cells(newrow, 2).Value = Worksheets(12).Cells(row, 25).Value
            newrow = newrow + 1
        End If
    Next row

Next col
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your line:

```
Worksheets(17).Cells(row, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

you are attempting to reference a cell using variable row before giving it a value. This could be what is causing your error.